# Arch Linux: Intel IRIS Driver

Tags: drivers, gpu, opengl

I've followed the insturctions on [1](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/merge_requests/283) to build and install the IRIS driver using `meson -Dgallium-drivers=iris.` Although running OpenGl programs after `export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=iris` just causes them to end in a memory dump like so:

```
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
WARNING: using "window" transform explicitly is deprecated (no-op); implied from "fft" transform.
WARNING: using "gravity" transform explicitly is deprecated (no-op); implied from "fft" transform.
WARNING: using "avg" transform explicitly is deprecated (no-op); implied from "fft" transform.
[1]    39337 segmentation fault (core dumped) glava
```

And `pinxi -Gx` returns:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.7 driver: intel unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
  resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1 128 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.3.4 
  direct render: Yes
```

Meaning the i965 Driver is being used.

Anyone know how I can use the IRIS driver instead?

Thanks for any help!

*Using `glava` for OpenGl testing*

*`glava` can be found [here](https://github.com/jarcode-foss/glava)*

*programs run perfectly fine in `su` maybe the IRIS driver is only available if the program has super user access?*

Answer (score 0):

> I've followed the insturctions on 1 to build and install the IRIS driver using meson -Dgallium-drivers=iris

The instructions are from a year ago and are bit useless now, because there have been several Mesa releases since the merge – the driver is already present on your system as soon as you install the normal 'mesa' package.

> Anyone know how I can use the IRIS driver instead?

Carefully remove your installed files, then reinstall the standard `mesa` package, and *then* your 'export' command should work fine.